# Link error with Cocotron

Tags: objective-c, linux, macos, cross-platform, cocotron

I've recently built a linux platform interface for Cocotron, and was able to build the Foundation framework with no errors.

However, when linking my objective-C project, I get a linker error:

/Developer/Cocotron/1.0/Linux/i386/Frameworks/Foundation.framework//libFoundation.so: undefined reference to `__gnu_objc_personality_v0'

I've done a bit of googling, but haven't found anything all that helpful.

Here's my ld command line (simplified a bit for readability):

```
Ld /Users/me/MyProject/build/Linux/Release/ENCLAnalyzer normal i386
    cd /Users/me/MyProject
    /Developer/Cocotron/1.0/Linux/i386/gcc-4.3.1/bin/i386-ubuntu-linux-gcc -arch i386 
    -L/Users/me/MyProject/build/Linux/Release 
    -L../../frameworks/Shared/FFmpeg/Linux/lib 
    -L/Developer/Cocotron/1.0/PlatformInterfaces/i386-ubuntu-linux/lib 
    -L/Developer/Cocotron/1.0/PlatformInterfaces/i386-ubuntu-linux/intel/mkl/9.0/lib/32 
    -L/Developer/Cocotron/1.0/PlatformInterfaces/i386-ubuntu-linux/intel/ipp/5.1/ia32/sharedlib
    -L/Users/me/frameworks/Shared/FFmpeg/Linux/lib 

    -F/Users/me/MyProject/build/Linux/Release 
    -F/Users/me/frameworks/Shared 
    -F/Developer/Cocotron/1.0/Linux/i386/Frameworks 
    -F/Users/me/frameworks/OtherProject/Linux 

    -filelist "/Users/me/MyProject/build/Linux/MyProject.build/Release/MyProject Linux.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyProject.LinkFileList" 

    -Wl,-rpath-link,/Developer/Cocotron/1.0/PlatformInterfaces/i386-ubuntu-linux/lib 
    -Wl,-rpath-link,../../frameworks/Shared/FFmpeg/Linux/lib 
    -Wl,-rpath-link,/Developer/Cocotron/1.0/PlatformInterfaces/i386-ubuntu-linux/intel/ipp/5.1/ia32/sharedlib
    -Wl,-rpath-link,/Developer/Cocotron/1.0/PlatformInterfaces/i386-ubuntu-linux/intel/mkl/9.0/lib/32
    -Wl,-rpath-link,/Developer/Cocotron/1.0/Linux/i386/Frameworks/Foundation.framework 

    -framework Foundation -framework MyFramework1 -framework MyFramework2 -framework MyFramework3 
    -o /Users/me/MyProject/build/Linux/Release/MyProject
```

I have a feeling that the foundation project needs to link to a library that it isn't, or that maybe it is linking to the wrong version of some library. But I'm not sure.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: There were some compiler updates in the Cocotron repository which fix
this issue. The the install script has been updated to pick these up and the new
version is here:

http://cocotron.org/Tools/Downloads/InstallCDT-2009-04-17.zip

Before using this, be sure to delete
/Developer/Cocotron/1.0/Downloads/gcc-4.3.1.tar.bz2  or it won't pick
up the new source. Make sure to specify Linux i386 when reinstalling.

i.e. `sudo ./install.sh Linux i386`

Thanks to [Christopher Lloyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28973/christopher-lloyd) for the info above, and for emailing me the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Which compiler are you using? The one from Cococtron, I hope? Take a look at [this](http://groups.google.com/group/cocotron-dev/browse_thread/thread/7d5d9d7bcd26fd6e) discussion.

The `__gnu_objc_personality_v0` occurs when you specify the incorrect compiler (say gcc for C++ code without the -x option). Try setting up some switches to tell g++ that you want to compile Obj-C code.

Comment: Thanks -- I'm using the Cocotron compiler.